# Populate List<Objects> From Mvc 3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I Have a Viewmodel based on Nominees . And i can have Multiple Nominees for the viewmodel.

I want to populate the Ilist From the view . Here are my viewmodels

```
public class DebitViewModel:IValidatableObject
{
    public string AgentName { get; set; }
    public Debit Debit { get; set; }

    public Policy Policy { get; set; }
    public PolicyType PolicyType { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }     

    public IList<PolicyType> PolicyTypes { get; set; }
    public List<Nominee> Nominees { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int,string> OccupationTypes { get; set; }        
}
```

I want to populate all Nominess automatically when i press submit . so how should i create by view and make it automatically populate List  automatically ? instead of serparate objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use editor templates:

```
@model DebitViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ... some input fields for the other properties that we are not interested in

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Nominees)

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and then you define a custom editor template for the `Nominee` model (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Nominee.cshtml`) which will automatically be rendered for each element of the `Nominees` collection:

```
@model Nominee

<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LastName)
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: it didnt work since its a list . a List of Nominees can't be shown by Nominee editor template :( i tried it its not showing the template fields .Where as if i do the same for single Nominee.  It shows all the template fields :)

Comment: @Joy, you probably did a mistake with the naming of your custom editor template. The name and location is very important. It must be `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Nominee.cshtml` and automatically the template will be rendered for each element of the collection.

Comment: But i saw only single nominee was working fine. i mean to say `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Nominee)` is working fine . if my editor template name and location would have been wrong then even it wont render single Nominee as wel :) but its working all right . The only problem is with `public List<Nominee> Nominees` :)

Comment: @Joy, you should use `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Nominees)` and not `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Nominee)`. And if your template name and location is wrong it will render a nominee. It's just that it will use the default template, not your custom template.

Answer (score 0):

say for example the `Nominee` looks like

```
public class Nominee{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

the view would look like

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Nominees.Count(); i++)
{ 
<tr>                                                           
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nominees[i].Name)</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nominees[i].Age)</td>
</tr>
}
```

read more about [**model binding to a list**](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Comment: Yes i know but i need to populate the list on HttpPost event . Would it populate the Nominess list automatically ?